# IBus XKB engine layouts don't work

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, ibus, input-language

I have IBus installed on Lubuntu 18.04.1 64-bit, and some languages work properly, while others just have the US English layout.

The Hangul Korean input engine (`ibus engine` output `hangul`) works (<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> gives `미` in Hangul mode), but Swedish and Spanish XBD input (`ibus engine` output `xbd:se::swe` and `xbd:es::spa`, respectively) do not (the keyboard layout is exactly the same as US).

The `m17n:sv:post` postfix Swedish layout seems to work (<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> gives `ö`).

This leads me to believe that there is a problem involving `xkb` IBus engines on my computer (whatever that means).

The output for `dpkg -l | grep ibus | grep -v libusb` is:

```
ii  gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64                   1.5.17-3ubuntu4                             amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - introspection data
ii  ibus                                    1.5.17-3ubuntu4                             amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - core
ii  ibus-gtk:amd64                          1.5.17-3ubuntu4                             amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+2 support
ii  ibus-gtk3:amd64                         1.5.17-3ubuntu4                             amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+3 support
ii  ibus-hangul                             1.5.0+git20161231-1                         amd64        Hangul engine for IBus
ii  ibus-m17n                               1.3.4-5                                     amd64        m17n engine for IBus
ii  ibus-qt4                                1.3.3-1build2                               amd64        qt-immodule for ibus (QT4) (plugin)
ii  ibus-table                              1.9.14-3                                    all          table engine for IBus
ii  libibus-1.0-5:amd64                     1.5.17-3ubuntu4                             amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - shared library
ii  libibus-1.0-dev:amd64                   1.5.17-3ubuntu4                             amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - development file
ii  libibus-qt1                             1.3.3-1build2                               amd64        qt-immodule for ibus (QT4) (library)
ii  libusageenvironment3:amd64              2018.02.18-1                                amd64        multimedia RTSP streaming library (UsageEnvironment classes)
```

The output for `ibus list-engines` (removed other languages):

```
...
language: Swedish
  xkb:se:dvorak:swe - Swedish (Dvorak)
  xkb:se:svdvorak:swe - Swedish (Svdvorak)
  m17n:sv:post - post (m17n)
  xkb:se::swe - Swedish
...
language: Korean
  hangul - Hangul
  m17n:ko:romaja - romaja (m17n)
  m17n:ko:han2 - han2 (m17n)
...
language: Spanish; Castilian
  xkb:es::spa - Spanish
  xkb:latam::spa - Spanish (Latin American)
...
language: English
  xkb:us::eng - English (US)
  xkb:gb:dvorak:eng - English (UK, Dvorak)
  xkb:gb:extd:eng - English (UK, extended WinKeys)
  xkb:us:altgr-intl:eng - English (international AltGr dead keys)
  xkb:us:colemak:eng - English (Colemak)
  xkb:us:dvorak:eng - English (Dvorak)
  xkb:ca:eng:eng - English (Canada)
  xkb:us:intl:eng - English (US, international with dead keys)
...
```

output for `setxkbmap -query` (same for all IBus layouts, even the non-US ones that work):

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
variant:    ,
options:    grp:shift_caps_toggle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed by deselecting the `Use system keyboard layout` check box in the `Advanced` tab of the `IBus Preferences` window (`ibus-setup`).

Now, the other keys work in Spanish and Swedish (<kbd>[</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> gives ò in Spanish and <kbd>[</kbd> gives å in Swedish).

[image: IBus Preferences window (ibus-setup) on the Advanced tab with "Use system keyboard layout" deselected]

Answer (score 1):

I have used ibus and xim in the past, and always had trouble. things started working much better after I switch to fcitx.

I'd recommend removing all ibus related package
installing fcitx instead, then running the reconfigure tool + im-config

```
sudo apt purge ibus
sudo apt install fcitx-hangul
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
im-config
```

here is my full list of fcitx package installed

```
fcitx/focal,focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 all [installed,automatic]
fcitx-bin/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-config-common/focal,focal,now 0.4.10-3 all [installed,automatic]
fcitx-config-gtk/focal,now 0.4.10-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-data/focal,focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 all [installed,automatic]
fcitx-dbus-status/focal,now 2016062301-3 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-frontend-all/focal,focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 all [installed,automatic]
fcitx-frontend-gtk2/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-frontend-gtk3/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-frontend-qt5/focal,now 1.2.4-1build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-hangul/focal,now 0.3.1-2 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-m17n/focal,now 0.2.4-2 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-module-dbus/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-module-kimpanel/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-module-lua/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-module-x11/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-modules/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-mozc/focal,now 2.23.2815.102+dfsg-8ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
fcitx-pinyin/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-table/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-table-emoji/focal,focal,now 0.2.4-2 all [installed]
fcitx-ui-classic/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
fcitx-ui-qimpanel/focal,now 2.1.3-2build1 amd64 [installed]
fcitx5-module-quickphrase-editor/focal,now 1.2.4-1build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-config4/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-core0/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-gclient1/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-qt5-1/focal,now 1.2.4-1build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-qt5-data/focal,focal,now 1.2.4-1build2 all [installed,automatic]
libfcitx-utils0/focal,now 1:4.2.9.7-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

hope this helps