# Ubuntu Mate disable xkb and use iBus

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-mate, ibus

In my computer I need keyboard language support for:

- English (US)
- Greek
- Japaneese

Hence the anthy (that I am used from 16.04LTS) is an option for me. Recently I ugraded from Ubuntu 16.04LTS into 18.04.2 LTS using the MATE variant.

Hence I installed `iBus` and `anthy`:

```
sudo apt-get install ibus ibus-anthy
```

And into language settings I have set the iBus Input option:
[image: Selecting IBus as Input method]

Also I have configured the iBus to ignore system settings as seen in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077787/540746)

And not due to double indicators in my system for input language I want to somehow "disable" the xkb/xinput/whatever powered one and use the iBus as universal language input for Greek, English and Japaneese(anthy) changing with 
`ALT`+`Shift` keyboard stroke.

Furthermore in my desktop I have 2 indicators one for iBus and one for xmodmap:
[image: language indicators]

When I switch between 2 language inputs via Alt+Shift the non iBus one indicates the input language.

The xmodmap layout is configured like that:

```
$ setxkbmap -query

rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     gr,us
variant:    ,
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

I tried temporary to disable xmodmap language input with:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

But it seems not only unable to change the language input but to get stick with english too. Also in this situation once I change the language input from iBUS indicator into greek I can use and change language inputs.

Also In this case one temporary "disabled" the xkbmap I get these settings:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

Thus as far as I understood the xmodmap overrides the iBus and I want to make it stop to do that and let iBus handle any language input. So in order to do that I need to completely disable the options in `setxkbmap` so how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with clean settings.

1. Reset MATE keyboard settings

   ```
   dconf reset -f /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/
   ```
2. Reset global system keyboard settings, fill `/etc/default/keyboard` with the following contents:

   ```
   # KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

   # Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

   XKBMODEL="pc105"
   XKBLAYOUT="us"
   XKBVARIANT=""
   XKBOPTIONS=""

   BACKSPACE="guess"
   ```

   and apply this settings into initramfs image with `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`.
3. Launch *Language Support* (or `gnome-language-selector`) and ensure that you have installed *English*, *Greek* and *Japanese* languages; also ensure that *Keyboard input system* is set to *IBus*.
4. Launch *IBus Preferences* (or `ibus-setup`) and add languages here and set up layout switching shortcut for them, logout and login back (or reboot).

   Note: I have set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> here, but it does not switch language. Alternative shortcut such as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> switches the language.

Comment: I followed your instructions but I lost the ability to type in Greek language even if I select it.

Comment: Oh, it is bad. Maybe there is a error in IBus or Xkb, which I did not see. Maybe other multi-lingual users may help here or on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Comment: Solved: https://askubuntu.com/a/1144490/540746