# Unable to type in Greek using iBus but can type Japaneese and English as well

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, ibus, input-language

Because I need to type in Japanese I switched my language input into `iBus` as seen in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1139936/540746). But whilst I am able to type in Japanese and in English I am unable to type into Greek even if I select the Greek Language.

My iBus Settings are the following:

[image: iBus Settings]
[image: iBus available languages]

Whilst the xkb input settings are the following (`/etc/default/keyboard`):

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

So how I can type back into Greek Language?

Comment: How do you select Greek? When IBus has been enabled, you should always use IBus to switch input languages, and ignore the other method which the Mate desktop offers.

Comment: Via keyboard shortcut provided via iBus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to do a bit of massaging but it is plausible. First of all you need to do the following steps:

1. Set the `Greek` Language into default system language via `xkb`.
2. Let iBus somehow to "synchronize" with `xkb`.
3. Make Anthy to use the English layout as the base layout.

The only issue is that 2 language indicators are shown, please get the information about the current input method via the iBus one.

For the step 1 replace the `/etc/default/keyboard` with the following:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBLAYOUT="us,gr"
XKBVARIANT=","
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp_led:scroll"
```

Then on step 2 deselect the following on `ibus-setup` (aka `IBus Preferences`):

[image: Option to deselect the appropriate input]

Then for the step 3 shows on `ibus-setup` Select the following tab and click as the steps the following screenshot shows:

[image: How to select Anthy Settings]

Then set the `us` keyboard variant as the default one as the following screenshot shows:

[image: Set us as the default keyboard layout]

Now you can type either in `Greek`, `Japaneese` and `English`. The language change is handled via `iBus` thus in order to change the language change keystroke (for example setting the Alt+Shift as language change keystroke) follow these steps:

[image: Change The input keystroke]